# High capacitance C0G (NPO) capacitor

Tags: capacitor, filter, passive-filter

[EDIT] : modified the value of cutoff frequency to 4.8kHz after reading the answer of Andy aka.
[EDIT2] Added somme information regarding comments under the question.

I need to build a LC high-pass filter that cuts at 4.8kHz with a fixed L value of 2.5 µH. This filter is installed in a cryostat working at cryogenic temperatures (4 Kelvin) with as little electromagnetic noise as possible. I am working with SQUID detectors, which are ultra sensitive superconducting magnetometers.

Parameters of the problem :

- Voltage rating : working in the µV range.
- Current : 1µA or lower,DC to 100kHz
- DC resistance : 0.01 to 0.1 Ohm

As the cutoff frequency is 1/(2 Pi sqrt(LC)), that means I need a capacitance of 440µF to make it work.

The thing is, at such such low temperatures most dielectric lose their capacitance. To my knowledge, the only dielectric that remains perfectly stable down to very low temperatures is C0G. PPS could also be an option, even if not perfectly stable. This fact is documented in [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00623399).

I've looked across Farnell, Radiospares, etc. and the highest C0G capacitor I could find has C = 0.47 µF , so I would need to wire a thousand of them in parallel which is not ideal. If I look at PPS capacitors the highest I could find is 22µF (ref : KEMET
SMR27.5226M50F13L4TRAY).

So my question is: do you know if it is doable to make a 400µF C0G (or if not possible PPS) capacitor? And if so, where to find it? I understand it would be extremely big, but this is not a big deal for me.

I know T or Pi high-pass filters could also be an option, but if possible I'd like to avoid adding additional inductance to my system for two reasons :

- This system is an extremely sensitive magnetic antenna, adding inductors would require careful magnetic shielding.
- Most magnetic materials lose their high permeability at ultra low temperatures. I'm sure I can design something with a bit of trial and error, it would require some more work.

Comment: I would think that getting a custom 400uF C0G capacitor made will cost you hundreds of thousands of dollars because the tooling doesn't exist. Try film capacitors instead but I think you may be going about things the wrong way.

Comment: can you use SMT on a PCB?  That would be a lot easier than leaded alternatives?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't increase your inductor value?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sure, but OP has already ruled that out. "*I've looked across Farnell, Radiospares, etc. and the highest C0G capacitor I could find has C = 0.47 µF, so I would need to wire a hundred of them in parallel which is not ideal.*" I also just noticed that the reason for C0G was temperature. Do film caps not work at that temperature either?

Comment: @DKNguyen, okay fair enough. But even some of the high value capacitors you can buy off the shelf are made by assembling several lower-value ones in parallel.

Comment: PPS seems pretty good according to your paper and that is certainly available in 400uF. Though, I imagine any capacitor you buy will actually have to be tested to see if it will work according to the paper since commercial caps aren't rated to cryogenic temperatures and just because a dielectric is C0G doesn't mean it is actually the same dielectric. It just has to match the C0G (or X7R, etc) characteristics). You can also compensate with increased capacitance at that temperature can't you?

Comment: What voltage rating does the capacitor need to have?

Comment: @DKNguyen you're right about PPS, I did a quick search but could not find any above 20µF. I'm going to look again.

Comment: @user4574 the tensions I am working with are in the µV range.

Comment: I’ve rolled back the latest amendment because it makes my answer look stupid. If you want to do this, then, once an answer is already provided, you must get agreement from the answerers and recognise in the amendment that the question has been modified following information provided by my answer. Anything less than this is not respectful.

Comment: @Andyaka I am very sorry about that, I did not mean to be disrespectful. Should I edit my question to acknowledge that it has been modified given your previous answer ?

Comment: That would be acceptable.

Comment: @Dimitri I easily found 400uF (larger even). On Digikey.

Comment: _"To my knowledge, the only dielectric that remains stable down to very low temperatures is C0G."_ - this paper says otherwise https://indico.fnal.gov/category/1299/attachments/140884/177214/cold_electronics_jpl.pdf

Comment: What voltage rating? What current is it conducting? What loss resistors are involved (that modify Q)? What Q-factor is it running at? You need to be clearer about these things. What is the actual 0.47 uF capacitor you found - please link to the data sheet or recognized buying site @Dimitri also, why can't the inductor be bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I would need to wire a hundred of them in parallel which is not
> ideal.

Wiring them by hand is not ideal.  But it's not a huge problem for an SMT machine.  There are plenty of places that will fabricate a 1-or-2-layer board and use their SMT machines to put hundreds of the same part on the board for very cheap.

Just doing a quick search on some vendor websites to find the cheapest NP0 capacitor in each size gives the following results.

[image]

Using some free software like KI-CAD to make a PCB design, and then sending it out to a board vendor to have them put on 468 x 0.94uF surface mount capacitors doesn't seem impractical.  You might pay something like $1775 for the parts, and probably under $100 for the PCB (unless you need a special grade of material or something).

Comment: But will the board survive at 4K??

Comment: I am not sure if this will hold at cryogenic temperatures but that's indeed a very good solution.

Comment: @Dimitri Obviously some research would need to be done to figure out which (if any) commonly available PCB materials could survive the cold.  You might just have to test some and write a paper on it (you already have the cryostat after all).

Comment: @Dimitri survival at 4K should be fine.  It's the cycling that's the issue (and everything becoming brittle when cold).  Most materials have done most of their contraction by 77K and liquid nitrogen is so much easier to obtain that I suggest you use that for initial testing. I've done this with microscope objectives and LED circuits (watch the colour change).

Answer (score 8):

> *I need to build a LC high-pass filter that \$\color{red}{\text{cuts at 30 kHz}}\$ with a fixed
> L value of 2.5 µH. As the cut-off frequency is 1/sqrt(LC), that means I
> need a capacitance of 440µF to make it work.*

$$F_C = \dfrac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\times \sqrt{\text{ 2.5 µH x 440 µF }}} = \text{ 4.8 kHz}$$

That should make life easier and note, that asking product recommendation questions are off-topic on this site (just in case you were).

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{You forgot about the 2π bit}}}$$

You are looking for 11.26 μF and not 440 μF: -

[image]

Image from [my crappy website high pass RLC calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20HPF/RCL%20HPF.html). You don't need to go there. I've added a link because site rules say I have to or the mods will be on me.

> *I've looked across Farnell, Radiospares, etc. and the highest C0G
> capacitor I could find has C = 0.47 µF, so I would need to wire a
> hundred of them in parallel which is not ideal.*

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{100 x 0.47 µF = 47 µF and not 440 µF}}}$$

> *So my question is: do you know if it is doable to make a 400µF C0G
> capacitor? And if so, where to find it? I understand it would be
> extremely big, but this is not a big deal for me.*

$$\color{purple}{\boxed{\text{My Dad always told me this: "measure twice and cut once"}}}$$

He was a joiner/carpenter.

Comment: '400 x 0.47uF = 47uF ...' not according to my calculator ;-)

Comment: @NMF + Andy I've corrected the typo there (text said a hundred, equation had 400), hope you don't mind.

Comment: See how math errors tend to snowball?? ;-)  Suitable analogy for 4K

Comment: I meant a filter that cuts all omega below 30kHz, not f. Sorry about that, should have made it clearer.

Comment: So only 24 caps of 0.47uF is needed. According to next answer approx 50 bucks, that's cheap compared to 4K, still don't understand why it is needed.

Comment: @Dimitri once an answer appears that provokes you into recognition that your question was flawed, you cannot just update the question without taking much more care about the changes you so recently applied. I have rolled back your question to the previous revision so, take note what you need to do and read what I said in a comment under your question.